# Java project with Groovy not compiling

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, compilation

I'm using eclipse with jdk1.7.0_21.

I have java project which contains some Groovy files. I installed the Groovy-eclipse featurs (as shown in the image below) [image: Groovy for eclipse]

but the project still has compiling error (the error is that in some classes I'm trying to import a groovy file and it is not probably)

What do I need to add/change in order to compile the project?

Is it possible to import groovy file in a java file? I mean: "import myproject.groovyfile;" while groovyfile is the groovy file instead of java class

Thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the groovy library to the classpath.

Right click the project, go to "Build path"->"Add library"->Groovy Runtime Libraries.

Another suggestion (which helped in this case):
Add a dummy groovy class to your project, clean and rebuild, and than remove the groovy class.

Comment: Thanx, I added the grooby library and now I have red X on the GROOVY_SUPPORT in "build path". What should I need to enter?

Comment: Just remove it then. Let's try adding it by right clicking the project and going down to "Groovy" if you have it in your menu. Hit the "Add groovy libraries to classpath".

Comment: I don't have "Groovy" in that menu (right click the project). Is there another way to do that? Do I need to add any jar to "build path"?

Comment: Well you can put the groovy-all-x.x.x.jar onto the classpath and it should work just fine. Found under /embeddable in the groovy dist. zip-file.

Comment: I add the groovy jar to build path, it didn't help. the question is, is it possible to import groovy file in a java file? I mean: "import myproject.groovyfile;" while groovy file is the groovy file instead of java

Comment: The problem solved: I open new project, add groovy class, the eclipse suggest me to add automatically "groovy runtime libraries". now it works! thank you all